# Team foundation server source control - changing .resx files

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have never use TFS version control...so I will try to explain problem I'm facing..
I have a small application for language localization...app make changes to .resx files of the project hosted on TFS...problem is that source control does't see that .resx files has been changed?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the file type options, try this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252452%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It might be what you're after.

Comment: Tricky part is that version control see and marks this files 'changed' if files has been changed trough visual studio (when working on project), but not if this localization application change them.. Thanks for suggestion, will try that..